# Capturing command-line output on win32 that hasn't been flushed yet

Tags: perl, command-line, winapi, capture

(Context:  I'm trying to monitor a long-running process from a Perl CGI script.  It backs up an MSSQL database and then 7-zips it.  So far, the backup part (using `WITH STATS=1`) outputs to a file, which I can have the browser look at, refreshing every few seconds, and it works.)

I'm trying to use 7zip's command-line utility but capture the progress bar to a file.  Unfortunately, unlike SQL backups, where every time another percent is done it outputs another line, **7zip rewinds its output before outputting the new progress data**, so that it looks nicer if you're just using it normally on the command-line.  The reason this is unfortunate is that normal redirects using `>`, `1>`, and `2>` only create a blank file, and no output ever appears in it, except for `>`, which has no output until the job is done, which isn't very useful for a progress bar.

How can I capture this kind of output, either by having every change in % somehow be appended to a logfile (so I can use my existing method of logfile monitoring) just using command-line trickery (no Perl), or by using some Perl code to capture it directly after calling `system()`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure which method 7za.exe uses to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer how to capture output that gets rewound, but it was a useful way of going about it that I ended up using.

For restores:

1. use `7za l` to list the files in the zip file and their sizes
2. fork `7za e` using `open my $command`
3. track each file as it comes out with `-s $filename` and compare to the listing
4. when all output files are their full size, you're done

For backups:

1. create a unique dir somewhere
2. fork `7za a -w`
3. find the `.tmp` file in the dir
4. track its size
5. when the `.tmp` file no longer exists, you're done

For restores you get enough data to show a percentage done, but for backups you can only show the total file size so far, but you could compare with historical ratios if you're using similar data to get a guestimate.  Still, it's more feedback than before (none).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to capture the output all at once then this is the code you want:

```
$var=`echo cmd`;
```

If you want to read the output line by line then you need this code:

```
#! perl -slw
use strict;
use threads qw[ yield async ];
use threads::shared;

my( $cmd, $file ) = @ARGV;
my $done : shared = 0;
my @lines : shared;

async {
    my $pid = open my $CMD, "$cmd |" or die "$cmd : $!";
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "$file : $!";
    while( <$CMD> ) {
        chomp;
        print $fh $_;         ## output to the file
        push @lines, $_;    ## and push it to a shared array
    }
    $done = 1;
}->detach;

my $n = 0;
while( !$done ) {
    if( @lines ) {            ## lines to be processed
        print pop @lines;   ## process them
    }
    else {
        ## Else nothing to do but wait.
        yield;
    }
}
```

Another option is using Windows create process.  I know Windows C/C++ create process will allow you to redirect all stdout.  Perl has access to this same API call: See [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Process).

Comment: When I try to run this script, I get `threads: Unknown import option: async`.

Comment: (The first code snippet I didn't actually try, because I'm pretty sure it's not what I'm after: I need to continually capture the output to get the progress bar, because it keeps changing thanks to this 'rewinding' thing.  A one-time statement accomplishing that seems like it would be pretty dark magic even for Perl...)

Comment: yeah I'm not sure ether.  For running the 2nd snip you'll probably have to install a library with CPAN.    I just know that CreateProcess can capture output,  idk how to do it with perl. I'm a *nix programmer sorry.

Comment: I put `async` over to the `threads::shared` line and it stopped complaining, but the result is the same as `>`, no output until the end.  Well, thanks for trying anyway, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening a [pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens) to read 7zip's output.

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately, it behaves exactly like `>` on the command line does: no output until the program is finished.